# Ошибка You don't have permission to access при активации tinycarousel.js

Tags: javascript, modx

Сайт [malner.ru](http://malner.ru/) 
Сделан на modx.
В шапке сайта карусель, при нажатии на кнопку для смены картинки, выводится ошибка:
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /assets/templates/default/ on this server."

В чём может быть проблема?
Обратил внимание, что в head есть такой код

```
<base href="http://malner.ru/assets/templates/default/" />
```

при переходе по [href="http://malner.ru/assets/templates/default/"](http://malner.ru/assets/templates/default/), выводится такая же ошибка.
Папки в пути assets/templates/default с доступом 777. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина? 
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено: 
На форуме modx подсказали, нужно было поменять местами вызовы скриптов:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jque‌​ry.min.js">
</script> <script src="js/jquery.tinycarousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас не активировалась карусель, попробуйте вызовы `$` заменить на `jQuery`.
Плюс в консоли ошибка: `http://malner.ru/assets/templates/default/js/jquery.tinycarousel..min.js` - в пути лишняя точка перед min.

Вообще, конечно, желательно заглядывать в консоль и пытаться понять, что там пишется.

Comment: Лишнюю точку перед ссылкой убрал. Это я сегодня активировал то, что увидел в папке с js, но tinycarousel.min.js не помог. Скажите пожалуйста, как заменить вызовы $ на jQuery, можете написать пример? Я уже попробую исправить по образцу. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Починили. На форуме modx подсказали, надо было просто поменять местами вызовы скриптов таким образом:                  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.tinycarousel.js"></script>`